# black and white pages not recognized by printer

Tags: pdftex, colors

I have a document which has color on about 25% of its pages. When I print it in the copy shop, the printer's technically supposed to recognize the b/w pages. However, all pages are registered as colored, i.e. the pages are color-enabled pages which happen to not have any colors on them (but I'm paying for the color-enabled-ness). Regrettably, the staff have to charge me for color because the printer's leased and they have to pay for color pages, so showing them that there's no color doesn't help me.

What are possible sources for b/w pages showing up like that?

Comment: How have you generated the PDF file? Which color package and color models you are using? What kind of images are on the b/w pages?

Comment: This looks off-topic to me: there's no TeX in the question, and it's really not clear that it's anything that can be solved at the TeX end.

Comment: @JosephWright - should've said it's a pdflatex document in the first place, will also add further info as requested by Heiko. Agree that it may be a non-tex problem, but may be a misconfiguration on my side in the tex code as well, might be worth finding out.

Comment: This question would fit on SuperUser with more detail, and they are better-placed to answer it than we are. Could an edit be made to 'flesh out' the issue, and I can then migrate.